# Font family "cursive" doesn't work in chrome mobile v47

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, fonts, mobile-chrome

I'm wondered why it doesn't work in chrome mobile browser v47 (latest atm), since it perfectly works at desktop one including different mobile device modes in developer tools.

Is there workarounds exist? At least, what it's original name I can find for the download?

Check this up:

```
<style>

* {
  font-family: cursive;
}

</style>

<div>
  I should be cursive even on mobile devices
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4kpn17g/)

Notice, it works in developer tools but doesn't from real mobile device one.

Comment: there is zero guarantee that any of the generic CSS font families do what you expect them to do. If I load your jsfiddle on my windows 8.1 + firefox setup I get "comic sans", which is not exactly "cursive"

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, :( rly pity

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In Firefox on desktop, you can change all default fonts with about:config. It's hard to find a script font that is actually readable though.

Comment: The question, from 5 years ago, was about Chrome on mobile, and my comment was to illustrate that the category keywords can't really be trusted =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans But my comment would also have been valid 5 years ago ;) While the question was about Chrome on Android, your comment was about Firefox on Windows! Anyway, I upvoted your answer, OK.

Comment: yes but my comment illustrated _why_ you can't trust CSS generic font families by showing that those classes don't even mean the same thing, cross-platform. Explaining how to then "fix it for that example platform" is reading the wrong thing as being the problem to solve ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never rely on generic family keywords to actually be "a specific font". There is no requirement for the browser to load a font that matches the keyword, technically it just needs to load "a" font. The [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#generic-font-families) is very explicit about this:

> "Generic font families are a fallback mechanism, a means of preserving some of the style sheet author's intent in the worst case when none of the specified fonts can be selected. **For optimum typographic control, particular named fonts should be used in style sheets**.
>
> "All five generic font families are defined to exist in all CSS implementations (they need not necessarily map to five distinct actual fonts)."

With my emphasis added to the part that explains that you are responsible for getting the right font loaded.

Comment: Is  there somewhere someone offers a solution to this? "For optimum typographic control, particular named fonts should be used in style sheets." How?

Comment: By either using the websafe font names, which in 2023 is pretty silly, or by using webfonts like google fonts, which has a million explainers and tutorials online and should be super easy to find with some simple web searching.

Comment: A web search brought me to this page. I'm still at it trying to find a solution elsewhere, but I'll try now the keyword webfont.

Comment: search for "how to use google webfonts" and take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering this problem as well.

When you use `font-family: cursive` you're actually allowing the browser to decide which font-family it generates for 'cursive'.

The solution is to be specific with your font-family instead of using the generic font.

```
serif         eg. Times New Roman, Palatino Linotype, etc.
sans-serif    eg. Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, etc.
cursive       eg. Comic Sans MS, Lucida Handwriting, etc.
fantasy       eg. Impact, etc.
monospace     eg. Courier New, etc.
```

So for `cursive` you'd want to specify `Comic Sans MS`, `Lucida Handwriting`, or another specific type that you were intending to implement.

Comment: This helped. The full list of font-families can be found here 

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp